# Memory leaks on expanding pre-allocated list through index

Tags: r

I have a pre-allocated list that I use in my code:

```
slopeList <-  vector('list',20)
```

When I copied/paste the code in the Rconsole I noticed that I could add more 
records then allocated without any error nor warning.

```
for (i in (200:220)) slopeList[[i]]<- 0
```

This runs without error nor warning. On the opposite entering manually the following line:

```
slopeList[[230]]
```

`Error in slopeList[[230]] : subscript out of bounds`
So the FOR loop could create a memory leak.

Is there a flag that I can set in my program to generate warnings or errors even if the list is accessed in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the difference in behaviour is that inside your `for` loop you are calling the function `` `[[<-` `` (which supports assigning to indices longer than the length to which the list was initialised) while outside the loop you are calling `` `[[` `` (which throws an error, because that element doesn't exist).

There are many ways to throw errors or warnings when such behaviour occurs, for example you could implement your own method to handle variables that belong to a certain "class" that handles assignments differently. The simplest way would be to make sure you refer to `slopeList` in your loop, e.g. `for (i in seq_along(slopeList)) {...}` would never exceed the length of the list

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know if the `[[<-` expands the list correctly (ie not generating memory leak)?

Comment: @Pilip I am not sure I understand the question, are you referring to implementing your own method?

Comment: Yes. In this code line `for (i in (200:220)) slopeList[[i]]<- 0` will this expand properly the list or could this generates memory leaks. Of course it could cause unwanted copies and/or longer processing times but my question is really on memory leaks.

Comment: @Pilip `[[<-` is R's default way of assigning the elements of a list. I'm not sure what you mean by "cause memory leaks". Of course if you do something like `x <- list(1, 2); x[[1000000000]]]` it will grow the list to have length 1 billion, and it will therefore occupy a large chunk of memory. So of course if you are not careful and you assign things this way you can cause it to crash.